# getElementById returns null but only with a few elements

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I need to get an `asp:Button` that is not located in the same file. I'm trying with `getElementId()` from the `Masterpage`. But it doesn't work with that specific element, I tried with some other elements in the same file and almost all of them worked. This is the code of the `WebForm`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/JCLMovies/PRUEBA.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="pruebawebS_index" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="body1">
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RPT">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="overlayone-border">
                            <img class="overlayinn-border-img" alt="overlay" src='<%# Eval("Thumbnail") %>' />
                            <div class="overlayinn-border">
                                <div id="hola" class="pe"><%# Eval("Title") %></div>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnMovie" style="display:none" onclick="BtnMovieInformation_Click" Text='<%# Eval("Thumbnail") %>' />
                                <div onclick="javascript:DivClicked('btnMovie'); return true;" class="Synopsis"><%# Eval("Synopsis") %> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is the `script` running from the `Masterpage`

```
<script>
        function DivClicked(id){
            var btnMovie = document.getElementById(id);
            if (btnMovie != null) {
                btnMovie.click();
            }
            console.log(btnMovie); 
        }            
</script>
```

I first executed this on a project without `Materpage` and everything works. I'm new on web development, so I would appreciate a simple explanation and some extra links or documentation to better understanding. Thank you so much!

Comment: Usually in asp.net the server sided controls are getting the `id` chained up from all parent server sided controls. Check the actual `id` of the button in the html output. Two common workarounds are using classes or the end-with option on `querySelector([id$=xxx])`.

Comment: It worked, as you said @Lain I only changed the `id` to the actual one in the html output. Replaced "btnMovie" for "ContentPlaceHolder1_RPT_btnMovie_1". Thank you so much!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8